# The Birthday Paradox

Tags: calculation-puzzle

You run an office that employs 23 people. What is the probability that two of your employees have the same birthday? For the purposes of the problem, ignore February 29.

Answer (score 3):

It's

> 0.507297

Because that's

> 1 - (1/365) ^ 23 * 365 * 364 * 363 * ... * 343